# Консольный чат на Python. Реализация регистрации в чате

Tags: python, сокет, websocket, клиент-сервер

Прошу вашего совета. Я хочу реализовать простенький чат на python c одним условием - регистрацией "участников чата". 
(Ник участника чата можно зарезервировать под себя, и введя пароль - зайти в чат под своим ником)

Саму логику обычного чата клиент-сервер я реализовал и проблем не возникало до тех пор, пока не появился процесс "регистрации" в чате.

Логика работы:

```
- Соединение с сервером
- Введение имени
- Утверждение, что имя введено верно
- Введение пароля
- Повторное введение пароля
- Пользователь заходит в общий чат
```

**Опишу проблему на словах:** 
Не получается реализовать метод/принцип/логику, при котором при регистрации пользователя сервер слушал бы только сокеты от данного пользователя. Проще говоря, любые сокеты от прочих пользователей сбивают всю логику. Получается так: происходит регистрация пользователя №1 (любой этап), заходит пользователь №2 и сбивает регистрацию пользователю №1. Не могу понять, как создать "сессию" с определенным пользователем. Прошу помощи. Код привожу ниже:

Код клиента:

```
import socket
import threading

SERVER_ADDRESS = ('localhost', 8125)
sor = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sor.bind(('', 0))
sor.sendto(('Connect to server').encode('utf-8'), SERVER_ADDRESS)


def reading_socket():
    while True:
        data = sor.recv(1024)
        print(data.decode('utf-8'))


potok = threading.Thread(target=reading_socket)
potok.start()


while True:
    message = input()
    sor.sendto((message).encode('utf-8'), SERVER_ADDRESS)
```

Код сервера:

```
import socket

SERVER_ADDRESS = ('localhost', 8125)

server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
server_socket.bind(SERVER_ADDRESS)
clients = []
members = {}
print("Server is running")

#ТУТ БОЛЬШАЯ ФУНКЦИЯ "РЕГИСТРАЦИИ"
#С ВВОДОМ ИМЕНИ, ПОДТВЕРЖДЕНИЕМ, ПАРОЛЕМ
def register_on_chat(port_address):
    register_data = 'Необходимо пройти регистрацию, введите свой ник: '
    server_socket.sendto(register_data.encode('utf-8'), address)

    def confirm_nickname(port_address):
        name, address = server_socket.recvfrom(1024)
        registration_data = f"Ваш ник {name.decode('utf-8')}? Введите Уes или No."
        server_socket.sendto(registration_data.encode('utf-8'), address)
        append_to_list(name, port_address)

    def new_nickmane(address):
        registration_data = 'Введите свой ник: '
        server_socket.sendto(registration_data.encode('utf-8'), address)
        confirm_nickname(address)

    def append_to_list(name, port_address):
        data, address = server_socket.recvfrom(1024)
        if data.decode('utf-8') == 'Yes':
            get_pass(name)
        elif data.decode('utf-8') == 'No':
            new_nickmane(port_address)

    def get_pass(name):
        pass_data_1 = f"Привет {name.decode('utf-8')} Введите пароль для своего ника: "
        server_socket.sendto(pass_data_1.encode('utf-8'), address)
        password_1, adr= server_socket.recvfrom(1024)
        pass_data_2 = "Повтори пароль"
        server_socket.sendto(pass_data_2.encode('utf-8'), address)
        password_2, adr = server_socket.recvfrom(1024)

        if password_1 == password_2:
            members[name.decode('utf-8')] = password_1.decode('utf-8')
            pass_data_3 = "Отлично, регистрация прошла успешно"
            server_socket.sendto(pass_data_3.encode('utf-8'), address)
            print(members)
        else:
            pass_data_4 = "Давай-ка попробуем снова"
            server_socket.sendto(pass_data_4.encode('utf-8'), address)
            get_pass(name)

    confirm_nickname(port_address)


while True:
    data, address = server_socket.recvfrom(1024)
    print(address[0], address[1])
    if address not in clients:
        clients.append(address)
        register_on_chat(address)
        text = "Регистрация прошла успешно. Добро пожаловать в чат!"
        server_socket.sendto(text.encode('utf-8'), address)

    for client in clients:

        if client == address:
            text_from_client = data.decode('utf-8')
            print(text_from_client)

            continue

        server_socket.sendto(data, client)
```

Спасибо за советы.

Comment: Почитайте про `socket.connect()` и `socket.accept()`. Подсказка: работу с соединением, полученным `socket.accept()`, можно организовать в отдельном потоке, таким образом у Вас каждый клиент будет обрабатываться независимо от других.

Comment: @МихаилМуругов у него датаграм) не выйдет ничего)

Comment: @eri Ваша правда, не увидел.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам нужно создать сессии для пользователей и отделить их от получения данных.

```
class Session:
    def __init__(self, address, sock):
        self.state = 'init'
        self.address = address

    def on_message(self, message):
        if self.state == 'init':
             answer = 'Необходимо пройти регистрацию, введите свой ник: '
        elif self.state == 'waitname':
             answer = f'Ваш ник {message}'         
             self.nick = message
        .......
        return answer



....

clients = {}

while True:
    data, address = server_socket.recvfrom(1024)
    session = clients.get(address, None)
    if not session:
        session = Session(address,server_socket)
        clients[address] = session
    answer = session.on_message(data.decode('utf-8'))
    self.sock.sendto(answer.encode('utf-8'), address)
    if session.state == 'chat':
        for other_session in clients.values():
            if other_session.state == 'chat':
                self.sock.sendto(f"{session.nick}: {data}\n".encode('utf-8'), other_session.address)
```

Класс Session будет хранить состояние чата и задавать следующий вопрос в зависимости от этого состояния. А словарь clients будет привязкой сессии к конкретному клиенту, а не только списком адресов.

Можно без класса, а состояние хранить в словаре.